# How do I fill only one element in geom_sf (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a map in ggplot and I want to highlight only one region, and the other with white fill. The standard fill is a dark grey, but I don't want to include manually all other regions.
Is there a way to automatize this (selecting the one region I'm interested and the others to white)?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = tudo_sul %>% filter(uf =='43'), 
          aes(geometry = geom_meso, 
              fill = nome_mesorregiao,
              ), color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Metropolitana de Porto Alegre' = 'blue')) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `na.value = "white"` inside `scale_fill_manual`

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can create a similar set-up with built-in data from the `sf` package:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$NAME[-1] <- NA
```

If we plot this with our single non-NA value being blue, we can see the rest are gray, as in your example:

```
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Ashe = "blue"))
```

[image]

But we can change the gray to white like this:

```r
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = NAME)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Ashe = "blue"), na.value = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>